# Jetpack Compose issue: "Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering"

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, snackbar

I'm experimenting with using Jetpack Compose to deploy a Compose snackbar in an activity otherwise written using View framework.

Presently I'm using it to try to deploy a snackbar when user clicks on a deeplink while app is running in background:

[image]

The result is a failed compilation with the following error:

```
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:50)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:235)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:68)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:55)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:41)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.doGenerateFilesInternal(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:195)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:331)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:58)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:170)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:434)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:120)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:357)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:299)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:159)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:622)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:100)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1713)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while generating code for:
FUN name:onNewIntent